# Double declaration and initialization of vector in a class C#

Tags: c#, vector

How to make this vector double declaration correctly?

```
var asset = new Vector<double>(new double[2 * N + 1], -N)
         
asset[-N] = S * Math.Exp(-N * dx);
```

In the definition: **asset[-N] = S * Math.Exp(-N * dx);** is showing the error

**The property or indexer "Vectorthis.[int]" cannot be assigned as it is read-only.**

Compiler error CS0200 - Property or indexer 'property' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

**full code below:**

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;

namespace TrinomialTree
{
    public class TrinomialTree
    {
        TrinomialParameters par;
        public TrinomialTree(TrinomialParameters pars)
        {
            this.par = pars;
            // Your program starts here:
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");

            // Declare and initialize the parameters
            TrinomialParameters myData;
            // Clewlow p. 55 C = 8.42534 for N = 3
            myData.sigma = 0.2;
            myData.T = 1.0; // One year
            myData.r = 0.06;
            myData.K = 100;
            myData.div = 0.0;
            myData.type = 'C';
            myData.exercise = false;
            myData.NumberOfSteps = 3;
            Console.WriteLine("How many timesteps: ");
            myData.NumberOfSteps = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            // Now define option-related calculations and price
            TrinomialTree myTree = new TrinomialTree(myData);
            Console.WriteLine("Price {0}", myTree.Price(100));
        }

        double Price(int strike)
        {
            int N = 2;
            int S = strike;

            Vector<Vector<double>> option;

            double sig2 = par.sigma * par.sigma;
            double dt = par.T / N;
            double nu = par.r - par.div - 0.5 * sig2;
            // Since trinomial is explicit FDM we have a constraint between
            // dt and dx (Clewlow inequality (3.27))
            double dx = par.sigma * Math.Sqrt(3.0 * dt) + dt * 1;
            double edx = Math.Exp(dx);
            // Initialize asset prices at *maturity*.
            // Notice that the start index is a negative number
            
            var asset = new Vector<double>(new double[2 * N + 1], -N);

            //Vector<double> asset = new Vector<double>(2 * N + 1, -N);

            //var x = new Vector<double>(new double[2 * N + 1], -N);

            asset[-N] = S * Math.Exp(-N * dx);

            for (int n = -N + 1; n <= N; n++)
            {
                asset[n] = asset[n - 1] * edx;
            }
            // Initialize option values at maturity.
            int minIndex = 0;
            option = new Vector<Vector<double>>(N + 1, minIndex);

            for (int n = N; n >= 0; n--)
            {
                for (int j = -n; j <= n; j++)
                {
                    option[n] = new Vector<double>(2 * n + 1, -n);
                }
            }
            int nn = N;
            if (par.type == 'C')
            {
                for (int j = -nn; j <= nn; j++)
                {
                    option[nn][j] = Math.Max(0.0, asset[j] - par.K);
                }

            }

            // Step back through lattice, start from maturity as given value at n = N.
            // European option
            if (par.exercise == false)
            {
                for (int n = N - 1; n >= 0; n--)
                {
                    for (int j = -n; j <= n; j++)
                    { // eq. 10.6
                        option[n][j] = disc * (pu * option[n + 1][j + 1] + pm * option[n + 1][j]
                        + pd * option[n + 1][j - 1]);
                    }
                }
            }
            else // American put only.
            {
                double tmp;
                for (int n = N - 1; n >= 0; n--)
                {
                    for (int j = -n; j <= n; j++)
                    { // eq. 10.6
                        tmp = disc * (pu * option[n + 1][j + 1] + pm * option[n + 1][j]
                        + pd * option[n + 1][j - 1]);
                        // American correction term
                        option[n][j] = Math.Max(tmp, par.K - asset[j]);
                    }
                }
            }

            return option[0][0];
        }

        public struct TrinomialParameters
        {
            // Option data
            public double sigma;
            public double T;
            public double r;
            public double K;
            public double div; // Dividend
            public char type; // 'C' or 'P'
            public bool exercise; // false if European, true if American
                                  // 'Numeric' data
            public int NumberOfSteps; // Nr. of subdivisions of [0, T]
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector-1.item?view=net-6.0 you can modify the item in Vector.... it is a `get` only property.

Comment: Why are you using `Vector<T>` in the first place? .NET's `Vector<T>` is completely unrelated to C++/STL's` `vector<>` type; instead, the .NET equivalent is `List<T>`.

Comment: I see you're [appropriating code from a book written in 2013](https://www.google.com/books/edition/C_for_Financial_Markets/4C-wInTw8uwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Clewlow%20inequality&pg=PA244&printsec=frontcover). The `vector` type they're using is their own, and it is **not** the `System.Numerics.Vector` type which postdates the book and was introduced in 2016.

Comment: Many thanks to all the help, that was exactly that, that implement a new type of vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `List<T>` instead of `Vector<T>`. The later is intended to optimize SIMD operations, not as a general purpose dynamic array. A `List<T>` would be the equivalent of a c++ vector.

But since I cannot see that you are adding any values, you might as well use a [jagged array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) or [multidimensional array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays). Or my preference, a custom class that wraps a 1D array but provides 2D indexing.

Even if you want SIMD optimizations, it might be argues that `Vector<T>` is not very effective. [This article compares `Vector<T>` with SIMD intrinstics](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/hardware-intrinsics-in-net-core/). The `Vector<T>` version is only about 30% faster, far from the theoretical 4 times speedup. The intrinstic version is much closer to the theoretical improvement.

Comment: Many thanks to all the help, that was exactly that, that implement a new type of vector.